# Weird margin in editable table

Tags: html, css, html-table, contenteditable

when I try to code an editable table in pure HTML & CSS, I run in an indesiderate issue. 
If the `table-layout` attribute is set to `auto` I have a strange margin applied to the right of the cell I'm editing.

Is there a way to keep the full width of the table without this strange margin applied to the content I'm edit?

Below the code snippet to better explain what I'm talking about:

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
table,tr,th,td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 10px;
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

```html
<table contenteditable='true'>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Header1</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
      <th>Header2</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
      <td>Content</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: table-layout : auto; not table-layout = auto;

Comment: corrected the attribute, thanks.